# Perl Moose class design

Tags: perl, oop, roles, moose

I have a class (`Foo`), Moose based, that has 4 properties, lets say:

```
SF1...SF4
```

each of type `HashRef[Any]`.

Currently all have default values. Later, we are going to get these values from a MySQL table.

My approach was, to have the `Foo` class consume roles depending on where the data comes from, I can store the `SF1...SF4` in a role called `Foo::DB` which it will provide the `SF1...SF3` with the default values from the database.

And also to have a role, `Foo::Local`, which will have the default values hard-coded, so later, when we will use the DB, I will only need to change the 'with....'.

Am I going in the right direction, or I should do it differently?

Comment: The phrase "...a role called Foo::DB which [...] will provide [...] the default values from the database.] raises a red flag. Defaults from a database? It's probably just a question of wording. But anyway, as with most other questions, it depends on why you are using this approach. The approach is obvious if it is for prototying or testing, but if you want some production code that can switch data sources, maybe something less tightly bound is better.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you need to populate the data from a role.  I think you can just use initializer subs.  Make your attributes lazy, and then define init_attribute subs.  The first time the value of the attribute is needed, if it is not already set, then initializer sub will be called to provide the value.  When you plug in the database you can simply teach your initializers how to query the database for the values.

```
package Foo;
has SF1 => ( is => 'rw', lazy => 1, isa => 'HashRef[Any]' );

sub init_SF1 {
    { hi => 'how are you' }
};
```

Alternatively, if you want to be able to go back and forth (e.g., for testing), then yes, you can bundle your initializers into the roles and apply the role depending on the situation.  Or you can just supply the values inline in your tests.  For instance

```
use Test::More;
use Foo;
my $foo = Foo->new(
    SF1 => { 
        row1 => 'fake test data', 
        row2 => 'also fake' 
    },
    SF2 => {},
); # now init_SF[12] will not be called
```

If you tell me *why* you're doing this, then I can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand you correctly.

You have four attributes that should be assigned a default value.

You have defined that default value in the MySQL database schema. What you would like to happen is that anytime you create a Foo instance, the default values will be populated from the defaults you have defined in the MySQL schema.

If I am correct in my understanding of what you are trying to do, then my advice is: *Don't do it that way* (unless this absolutely a requirement to your project).  Define the default values of your attributes using Moose's default or builder properties.

```
has 'bar' => (
    default => 'fubar',
);
```

If you were to lookup the default values that have been set in the database schema instead of defining them in your class you will create more work for yourself, add unnecessary complexity to your program, and will be adding expensive database calls that could be avoided. You would need to parse the database schema and determine what the defaults should be for the given attribute. You would either need to do this every time you created a new object (expensive) or create a cache of the default values. Sure you *could* create a Moose extension that implements some magic and does this for you transparently. Seems like a lot of work for a not-so-appealing solution. I would just use Moose's 'default' attribute property unless you have a *really* good reason not to.

Comment: Also, you may or may not be interested in using an ORM (object relational mapping) frame. I wrote a module called Storm that handles storing and retrieving of Moose objects a to SQL database. It takes a different approach to many object-relational-mapping frameworks - you don't need to provide a schema or spend much time designing the database. You create your classes, making sure the have the Storm::Role::Object role applied. Storm can then setup and manage your database tables for you. Storm is still in beta but is being used in production code. Other notable ORM's are Fey::ORM andd KiokuDB.